# Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android

Hello Guys i found this errors while generating sign apk.

```
Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

My configuration - Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Are you using a 64bit JRE and 64bit android studio?

Comment: yes indeed i am using  64bit JRE and 64bit android studio

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: 6.00 GB (4.96 GB Usable)

Comment: It Worked Thanks ALot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the java version used by the project.
It can be different from the one used by Studio.

For example :

[image]

Comment: my project is using C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Comment: So it is a 32 bits :-) (because of x86) Check with C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java -version

Comment: oh so . my System environment  also shares the same path.

Comment: Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java -version is 8.0.1010.13

Comment: Yep, if you don't see something like "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server", then it is a 32 bits

Comment: so what to do now ? i have now changed my project path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 and System environment to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102/bin

Comment: Well if it's a 64 bits, the APK generation should be ok ?